# Setting up user login with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to android and firebase.  I have the project setup at firebase and is connected.  I know i must have some code mistakes that are preventing my user logins to get to firebase. The app starts fine, and the AlertDialog works. The problem is after i enter email, username, and password. Thats when the app crashes and i dont see any users added to firebase. Any help would be appreciated.  Please be noob friendly as i am just learning.

```
public class CreateAccount extends AppCompatActivity implements ProgressGenerator.OnCompleteListener {
    private EditText emailAddress;
   // private EditText userName;
    private EditText password;
    private String userId;
    private ProgressGenerator progressGenerator;
    private ActionProcessButton createAccountButton;

    public CreateAccount() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);

        emailAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEmailId);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNamePasswordId);
        //userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameAccountId);

        progressGenerator = new ProgressGenerator(this);

        createAccountButton = (ActionProcessButton) findViewById(R.id.userNameCreateAccountButtonId);

        createAccountButton.setMode(ActionProcessButton.Mode.PROGRESS);
        createAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setCreateAccount();
            }
        });


    }


    private void setCreateAccount() {

        final String uEmail = emailAddress.getText().toString();
        //final String uName = userName.getText().toString();
        final String uPword = password.getText().toString();

        if (uEmail.equals("") ||  uPword.equals("")) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CreateAccount.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Empty Field");
            dialog.setMessage("Please Complete All Fields");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        } else {


            final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://texter-20d04.firebaseio.com/");

            progressGenerator.start(createAccountButton);
            createAccountButton.setEnabled(false);
            emailAddress.setEnabled(false);
            password.setEnabled(false);

            ref.createUser(uEmail, uPword, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {

                    logUserIn(uEmail, uPword, ref);

                    //create a new branch with username

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    // there was an error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }


    }

    private void logUserIn(final String uEmail, final String uPword, final Firebase ref) {

        if (!uEmail.equals("") || !uPword.equals("")) {
            ref.authWithPassword(uEmail, uPword, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                    userId = authData.getUid();
                    Log.v("USER ID: ", userId);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

        startActivity(new Intent(CreateAccount.this, ChatActivity.class));

    }

}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "texter.rednak71.com.texter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I managed to get login, registration and forgot password done in 20 minutes thanks to this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 0):

Another android enthusiast here: I'm learning too, and I think you could change some things:

- First, we (the community) need to know where you have the error using the debugging method (The icon is a green bug with a play icon), so put some breakpoints and click on the button mentioned.
- Second, as [firebase says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write):

> By default, read and write access to your database is restricted so
>   only authenticated users can read or write data. To get started
>   without setting up Authentication, you can configure your rules for
>   public access. This does make your database open to anyone, even
>   people not using your app, so be sure to restrict your database again
>   when you set up authentication.

So, I recommend you authenticate users with their emails, so [read this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth). You will realize that you have to comment this

```
final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://texter-20d04.firebaseio.com/");
```

Because the user doesn't have permissions to write on the database without being authenticated first. And change the method

```
ref.createUser(...
```

Because you need the method **signInWithEmailAndPassword** to add users with their email.

Try to do these things and tell me. I hope it helps and If I'm wrong, please, correct me.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a combination of Firebase clients:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

This will not work.

Please use a tutorial that is made for a version of Firebase (anything with 9.x) or stick to the [official Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).